# question on spectral sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

suppose $p:X\times Y \rightarrow Y$ is a second projection. Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X\times Y$. Then $H^0(Y,R^1p_*F)$ is part (i.e. fits in a long exact sequence) of $H^1(X\times Y, F)$, using leray spectral sequence.

I wanted to consider the cohomology of tensor product $H^0(Y,(R^1p_*F)^{\otimes 2})$.
Is this part of a leray spectral sequence.

I tried to take the external tensor product $F\times F$ on $(X\times Y)\times (X\times Y)$, and take direct image $R^2(P_{2,4})_*(F\times F)$ on $Y\times Y$.
This term has $R^1(p_2)_*F\times R^1(p_4)_*F$ as a summand. 
Pullback along diagonal $\Delta_{XY}$ gives

$$
H^0(X\times Y\times X\times Y, F\times F)\rightarrow H^0(X\times Y,F\otimes F)
$$
Is this compatible with pullback along diagonal $Y\rightarrow Y\times Y$ with following
$$
H^0(Y\times Y, R^1p_*F \times R^1p_*F) \rightarrow H^0(Y,(R^1p_*F)^{\otimes 2}).
$$
 Question is : is $H^0(Y,(R^1p_*F)^{\otimes 2})$ a part of long exact sequence containing $H^0(X\times Y,F\otimes F)$.

thanks.

Comment: $H^0(Y,R^1p_*F)$ is not a summand of $H^1(F)$. The spectral seuence only gives an exact sequence
$$
0 \to H^1(Y,R^0p_*F) \to H^1(F) \to H^0(Y,R^1p_*F) \to H^2(Y,R^0p_*F).
$$
and the last map is quite often nontrivial.

Comment: thaqnks..i modified the question.

Comment: Derived pushforward is not compatible with tensor products. So, I would not expect such a relation. 